# Conflicting Error Messages about Initialising a Variable

Tags: c, initialization, cs50

Here's my code:

''''

```
int main(void)
{   
    int j;
    int i;
    int k;
    int n;
    int w;
    
    
    do
    {
       int j = get_int("Height: \n ");
    }
    while (j < 1 || j > 8);
    
    
    for (i=0; i<=j; i++)
    ;
    {   
        w = 6-i;
        for (k=0;k<=w;k++)
        ;
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        
        for (n=1; n<=j; n++)
        ;
        
        {  
            printf("#");
        }
        
        printf("  "); 
        
        for (n=1; n<=j; n++)
        ;
        {  
            printf("#");
        }
    }
    
}
```

''''
I keep receiving these error messages, with one telling me that I need to initialise J while the other one tells me that there's a problem with that. What should I do? I would really appreciate any help, thank you!

```
 mario1.c:15:12: error: declaration shadows a local variable
      [-Werror,-Wshadow]
       int j = get_int("Height: \n ");
           ^
mario1.c:6:9: note: previous declaration is here
    int j;
        ^
mario1.c:17:12: error: variable 'j' is uninitialized when used
      here [-Werror,-Wuninitialized]
    while (j  8);
           ^
mario1.c:6:10: note: initialize the variable 'j' to silence this
      warning
    int j;
         ^
          = 0
```

[Error Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9tub.png)

Comment: Please paste error messages as text directly into the question.

Comment: `int j = get_int("Height: \n ");` that variable only exists inside the `do/while` loop. All the other `j` variables are a different variable, declared on the first line of the function, and that is the one that is unintialised.

Comment: None of your for loops do anything, remove the `;`

Comment: The `j` in `while (j < 1 || j > 8);` is the (uninitialised and unchanged) `int j` at the top, not the `int j` inside the loop. They are different variables, sharing the same name.

Comment: @WeatherVane  thanks! should i add another initialised j above that section then?

Comment: No, not only is it poor to use single-letter identifiers, but using more than one of them of the same name leads to confusion and error. The solution is to not define `j` *inside* the loop.

Comment: @WeatherVane, got it thanks. the cs50 instructor used them so i followed along, but definitely see where you're coming from. the only thing is, this "j" variable was supposed to be the same variable 

essentially, i'm taking the output from the do while loop and using it in later for loops - is there a way to continue to do this?

Comment: Yes as in one answer: define `int j` once (at the first place where you have it), so it can be used throughout `main()` function. Thereafter just use `j = ` instead of `int j = `

Comment: @WeatherVane got it thank you so much! one last thing - why does writing int before j define a new variable, i thought it just indicated what type of output you would get

Comment: Because it is inside a `{` code block `}` and has a different *scope*. So a new variable is created with the same name, and it "shadows" (obscures) the first one. Then at the end of the code block, it no longer exists, so any reference to `j` will be to the first definition – **including** the `j` in the `while()` condition.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
int j;

do
{
   int j = get_int("Height: \n ");
}
while (j < 1 || j > 8);
```

You define a brand new variable `j` inside the loop. This variable *shadows* the variable of the same name outside the loop. The variable `j` inside the loop exists only inside the curly-braces, its scope and life-time ends with the closing brace `}`.

The variable outside the loop, which is used in the loop condition, is indeed uninitialized.

The simple solution is to not define a new variable in the loop:

```
int j;

do
{
    j = get_int("Height: \n ");
}
while (j < 1 || j > 8);
```

Comment: got it thank you! to clarify, i thought the "int" was necessary to indicate that the output would be an integer. did i mix this up with initialisation?